# Exception catching mechanism, C++

Tags: c++, c++11, exception

Consider this code:

```
int main()
{
    try 
    {
        throw std::range_error("");
    }
    catch (std::bad_alloc) 
    {
        std::cout << "AAAA" << std::endl;
        throw;
    }
    catch (std::range_error) 
    {
        std::cout << "BBB" << std::endl;
        throw;
    }
    catch (std::exception)
    {
        std::cout << "CCC" << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "DDD" << std::endl;
}
```

Here I throw an exception of type `std::range_error` and trying to catch it.
Logically the first `catch` block cannot catch it because of type mismatch(`std::bad_alloc` and `std::range_error`).
The second catch block must catch it because they are the same types of `std::range_error`.
And also, when I rethrow the exception in second catch block it must be caught in the third catch block.

So my output must be

```
BBB
CCC
DDD
```

But I only get the `BBB` output with the termination.

Can anybody please explain me the behavior??

Comment: Your second throw did not occur in a `try` block. So it can't be caught.

Comment: It doesn't work that way.  Each try-catch block only gets one shot at the exception no matter how many catch clauses there are.  Exceptions thrown by any catch clause are not caught in that try-catch block.

Comment: that means that even if I have many catch blocks of the exception type, only the first one will catch the exception, am I correct?

Comment: @EduardRostomyan no. It means they catch only exceptions thrown inside a try statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you re-`throw` an exception, you are throwing it completely out of the context of the current exception handling block.... So,

```
try 
{
    throw std::range_error("");
}
catch (std::bad_alloc) 
{
    std::cout << "AAAA" << std::endl;
    throw;
}
catch (std::range_error) 
{
    std::cout << "BBB" << std::endl;
    throw;
}
catch (std::exception)
{
    std::cout << "CCC" << std::endl;
}
```

is **one** exception handling block. Therefore, on meeting the first `throw` in any of the `catch` blocks, it leaves the whole block to look for another handling block (*try-catch*) outside the current scope. if not found, the program terminates.

Please see [`try-catch` block in C++](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/try_catch)

To print as you initially thought ... [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3966885d5f2f1f39) ...

```
int main()
{
    try{
        try{
            try{
                throw std::range_error("");
            }
            catch (std::bad_alloc) {
                std::cout << "AAAA" << std::endl;
                throw;
            }
        }
        catch (std::range_error) {
            std::cout << "BBB" << std::endl;
            throw;
        }
    }
    catch (std::exception){
        std::cout << "CCC" << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "DDD" << std::endl;
}
```

Prints:

```
BBB
CCC
DDD
```

For the record: please avoid using exceptions for control flow that could be done with simple `if-else` ladder in production code

Answer (score 5):

To re-catch the range_error and new outer try catch block is required.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  //outer try catch ------------------------
  try { 

    // inner try catch ---------------------
    try 
    {
      throw std::range_error("");
    }
    catch (std::bad_alloc) 
    {
      std::cout << "AAAA" << std::endl;
      throw;
    }
    catch (std::range_error) 
    {
      std::cout << "BBB" << std::endl;
      throw;
    }
    // -------------------------------
  }

  catch (std::exception)
  {
    std::cout << "CCC" << std::endl;
  }
  // --------------------------------

  std::cout << "DDD" << std::endl;
}
```

Output

```
BBB
CCC
DDD
```

Answer (score 4):

This `throw`:

```
catch (std::range_error) 
{
    std::cout << "BBB" << std::endl;
    throw; // <== this one
}
```

isn't itself within the body of a `try`, so when the exception handling mechanism will keep going out one scope at a time until it finds one. Since there is no other outer `try`, the exception isn't caught at all.

There is no reentrance in exception handling.